# Browse and modify an SQL dump from MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import, mysql-workbench

I have a mysqldump from an SQL server and i want to open it in a program like MySQL Workbench or DBeaver so that i can easily search it and remove some values etc.

I'm trying to use MySQL Workbench however am unsure if i can import this SQL DUMP directly into here from the file like this. I have created in a new model and clicked import and it seems to show all my tables however they are empty.

Is this possible and how would i go about this?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench can restore a dump without loading it first into an editor (and hence can even handle gigabyte sized dumps). For this go to the `Data Import/Restore` admin section,

[image]

select your dump, set options (e.g. what of the dump to restore) and click `Start Import` to start the process.

However this doesn't allow to change the dump and because of usual dump sizes even browsing them is often not possible. You can try to load the dump file into an editor if it is not too large (say around 250MB, depending on system RAM). If it is much larger you can only try special tools like hex editors (which load large files piece by piece).

Comment: Thanks, yeah the file in question is only 20MB so should be fine to browse atleast. I will have a little look at this but what can you do it not browse / modify? I loaded it onto a server with phpmyadmin in the end which seems like it was better suited for my purpose now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, MySQLDump exports the database to an sql script with a .sql file extension?

In MySQL Workbench, open this file Using File->Open SQL Script or alternatively <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Running the script should then create the database

Comment: I will have a look at this got all my tables showing so just need to find the run script button i guess

Comment: Hi @SEarle1986 I can load the .sql script however the execute buttons are grayed out. My .sql file is about 8MB in size. I notice all of this is done in "Unconnected" mode. Is that the reason why the buttons are grayed out? Maybe MySQL Workbench can only work with server databases?

Comment: Was also getting the experience that the execute buttons were grayed out.